# Set label on group multiplot in gnuplot

Tags: linux, graph, plot, gnuplot

Im plotting one picture with 4 different graphs using gnuplot. Labels for their x and y axes have the same meaning. If Im plotting it like this:

```
set multiplot layout 2,2 rowsfirst

set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"


set title offset -3,-3

set xrange [20:70]
set yrange [0:15000]
set title "Plot 1" 
plot 'data5.list' u 2:1 w lp pt 7 lt 7 lc rgb 'red' notitle
set xrange [20:70]
set yrange [0:15000]
set title "Plot 2" 
plot 'data5.list' u 2:1 w lp pt 7 lt 7 lc rgb 'red' notitle
set xrange [20:70]
set yrange [0:15000]
set title "Plot 3" 
plot 'data5.list' u 2:1 w lp pt 7 lt 7 lc rgb 'red' notitle
set xrange [20:70]
set yrange [0:15000]
set title "Plot 4" 
plot 'data5.list' u 2:1 w lp pt 7 lt 7 lc rgb 'red' notitle


unset multiplot
```

I have all four graphs and their labels, but I want to achieve to have one label for all four of them, as in this [example](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSow2HFNWt-pOpuOo8a943O0J4iQJ4QCWQHt8sTdunRy21gZ2B-Ww) .

I tried with unset label for other 3 plots, but I get labels only on first of them, while the other do not have labels at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `xlabel` and `ylabel`, you may want to go with `set label`. For example,

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gnuplot

datafile='tmp.dat'          # file to plot

set xlabel " "              # no x-label
set ylabel " "              # no y-label

# assuming all plots have same x and y range
set xrange [-2:2]           
set yrange [-4:4]

# same setting for all graph titles
set title offset -3,-3

# puts x-label and y-label manually
set label 1 'x axis' at screen 0.49,0.02
set label 2 'y axis' at screen 0.01,0.5 rotate by 90

# now the graphs: notice that rowsfirst is given by default
set multiplot layout 2,2
  do for [i=1:4]{
    set title 'plot '.i
    plot datafile u 2:1 w lp pt 7 lt 7 lc rgb 'red' notitle
    unset label 1
    unset label 2
  }
unset multiplot

reset
```

If all plots can be done by the same line-syntax, then I recommend to use a do-loop (as in the example above) instead of copying it each time.

Notice that `gnuplot` will put the labels 1 and 2 each time a graph is plotted. That is why I put `unset label 1` and `unset label 2` inside the do-loop, so the labels are placed just in the first iteration.

---

If you want to have something similar to the example you provided, then I recommend to use this script (explained through the comments):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gnuplot

datafile='tmp.dat'          # file to plot

# parameters to configure margins of each graph
x0=0.1                      # left margin all graphs
y0=0.99                     # top margin all graphs
lengthx=0.4                 # horizonal length of each graph
lengthy=0.4                 # vertical length of each graph
spacex=0.04                 # horizontal space between each graph
spacey=0.04                 # vertical space between each graph

# This is a macro: configure the top, right, left, and bottom margins of each graph.
# It will depend on the value of i and j.
set macro
i=0; j=0;
SETMARGINS = "set tmargin at screen (y0-i*(lengthy+spacey));\
              set bmargin at screen (y0-i*(lengthy+spacey)-lengthy);\
              set lmargin at screen (x0+j*(lengthx+spacex));\
              set rmargin at screen (x0+j*(lengthx+spacex)+lengthx)"

# Assuming all plots have the same x and y range. If not, set it in each plot below
set xrange [-1.5:1.5]
set yrange [-4:4]

# general setting for plot titles
set title offset -3,-3

# don't worry about the axis labels for now
unset xlabel
unset ylabel

#############################################################
set multiplot

  ##### top-left 
  i=0; j=0;
  @SETMARGINS                       # calling the macro for (i,j)=(0,0)
  set format x ''                   # no numbers in x-axis
  set format y '%.1f'               # but with numbers in y-axis

  set title 'plot 1'
  plot datafile u 2:1 w lp pt 7 lt 7 lc rgb 'red' notitle

  ##### top-right
  i=0; j=1;
  @SETMARGINS                       # calling the macro for (i,j)=(0,1)
  set format y ''                   # no numbers in x nor y-axis

  set title 'plot 2'
  plot datafile u 2:1 w lp pt 7 lt 7 lc rgb 'red' notitle

  ##### bottom-left
  i=1; j=0;
  @SETMARGINS                       # calling the macro for (i,j)=(1,0)
  set format xy '%.1f'              # numbers in both axes

  set title 'plot 3'
  plot datafile u 2:1 w lp pt 7 lt 7 lc rgb 'red' notitle

  ##### bottom-left 
  i=1; j=1;
  @SETMARGINS                       # calling the macro for (i,j)=(1,1)
  set format y ''                   # no numbers in y-axis

  # now we set the x and y labels for the 4th plot, and move them to the desired position
  set xlabel 'xlabel' offset screen -0.5*(spacex+lengthx),0.0
  set ylabel 'ylabel' offset screen -lengthx-1.5*spacex,0.5*(spacey+lengthy)
  set title 'plot 4'
  plot datafile u 2:1 w lp pt 7 lt 7 lc rgb 'red' notitle

unset multiplot

reset
```

more info: [gnuplotting](http://www.gnuplotting.org/multiplot-placing-graphs-next-to-each-other/)